# Spark no such field METASTORE_CLIENT_FACTORY_CLASS

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, amazon-emr

I am trying to query a hive table using spark in Java. My hive tables are in an EMR cluster 5.12. Spark version is 2.2.1 and Hive 2.3.2.

When I ssh into the machine and I connect to the spark-shell I am able to query the hive tables with no issues.

But when I try to query using a custom jar then I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1067)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:141)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:637)
    at package.Session.executeQuery(Session.java:48)
    at com.etl.cli.ETL.main(ETL.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:635)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: METASTORE_CLIENT_FACTORY_CLASS;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.build(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1064)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: METASTORE_CLIENT_FACTORY_CLASS
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClientFactory(Hive.java:3011)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3006)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3042)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1235)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:175)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<clinit>(Hive.java:167)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:266)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
        ... 25 more
```

My pom looks like this :

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Instantiating the session:

```
 SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse");
        conf.set("hive.metastore.client.factory.class",
                "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore.Client.Factory");

        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("Spark Application")
                .master("yarn-cluster")
                .config(conf)
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .getOrCreate();
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of debugging I realised another dependency in my pom was causing this error. When I removed the hive-jdbc client the application worked fine.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```