# Issues in passing application configuration parameters to spark application

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I created an object using Spark/Scala to load data from an Oracle source to Hive Table. Database Password is passed through application.properties through typesafe.ConfigFactory.
I ATTEMPTED APPLICATION.CONF IN MY USER FOLDER and also IN CLASSPATH IN ANOTHER ATTEMPT with below spark-submit.

On every attempt I encounter error saying "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':".
which indicates like properties not reached configFactory methods
Can someone help me what am missing?

```
//my object snippet
object LoadFromOracleToHive {
  def SaveToHive(spark :SparkSession):Unit = {
    try {
      val appConf = ConfigFactory.load(s"application.conf").getConfig("my.config")
      val sparkConfig = appConf.getConfig("spark")  //  config.getConfig("spark")
      val df = spark
        .read
        .format("jdbc")
        .options(Map("password" -> sparkConfig.getString("password")  , "driver" -> "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"))
//my application.conf       
my.config {
  spark {
    password = "password"
  }
}
//my spark-submit
spark-submit --class LoadFromOracleToHive \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--driver-memory 4g \
--executor-memory 8g \
--num-executors 15 \
--executor-cores 5 \
--conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=512m  \
--queue csg \
--jars /home/myuserfolder/ojdbc7.jar  /home/myuserfolder/SandeepTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
--queue /home/myuserfolder/application.conf \
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=-Dconfig.file=/home/myuserfolder/application.conf \
--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=-Dconfig.file=/home/myuserfolder/application.conf
```

Comment: How did you construct your `sparkSession` ? Did you "`enableHiveSupport`" ?

Comment: Below is the error message I receive while enableHiveSupport.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: rpcTimeout;
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: rpcTimeout
        at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.InitializeClientInitParamsFromConf(MapRFileSystem.java:368)

Comment: Can you verify you don't have conflicting dependencies in your classpath ?
Look at this link for instance : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728091/spark-no-such-field-metastore-client-factory-class

Comment: Adding above dependencies to my pom.xml resolved my issue. Thank you a lot baitmbarek !!